# I had an Stack Exchange account for years but just moved to a new company

Tags: discussion, login

I've been active on Stack Exchange for a number of years now, but recently moved to a new company... it seems that I have to create a new account to log in now since my old account used my previous company email?  Anyway to pick up where I left off without losing my history?

Comment: I've flagged this for moderator attention to have this migrated to meta.

Comment: You're leaving a lot up to guesswork. Can you at least link to your other account?

Comment: When I attempt a login it asks for my email... the email is from a company I no longer work for hence I cannot get the password reset email to get into that account.  What do you mean by "link to"

Comment: Okay, somehow I remembered my old password and was able to log into my original account.  All is good!